# How to select a specific element inside editor (tinymce 4.x)

Tags: image, select, tinymce, selection

I have an image inside the editor using plugin 'imagetools' and added an additional image operation on it (that works fine). After this custom operation is done I'm loosing the selection of the image, that I try to select again. 
Since the image is initally selected I would have the chance to capture some information to select it again after custom image operation. But whatever I try it doesn't work:

Before operation (while the image is selected by user):

```
var node = tinymce.activeEditor.selection.getNode();
```

After operation:

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.dom.select(node);
```

-> nothing selected

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.select(node);
```

-> Error: Argument 1 ('refNode') to Range.setStart must be an instance of Node

I assume the solution is pretty simple. I just don't get it and tinymce documentation is not really helpful on this.

Answer (score 0):

Found it: You can set a bookmark before doing any changes on or inside the element:

```
var bookmark = tinymce.activeEditor.selection.getBookmark();
```

After element processing you set back the bookmark:

```
tinymce.activeEditor.selection.moveToBookmark(bookmark);
```

Now your previously selected element should will be selected again.